# My .py file instantly closes when I open it(attempted to fix with solutions from other threads on this website)

Tags: python, multithreading

So I had been given the task to make a remainder calculator in python. My code is:

```
answer1 = int(input("Enter number: "))
answer2 = int(input("Enter the number you want to divide by: "))
receive_answer1 = answer1 // answer2
remaining = answer1 % answer2
print("Answer is {} and the remainder is {}".format(receive_answer1, remaining))
input("prompt: ")
```

As you can see, I have inputs  so the python file should not close instantly, which is a solution I have seen on other threads. I have changed environment variables, turned it into a .bat file, etc. to no avail. So, I need some specific help. This happens on any file I save. I am using Windows 10 Spyder IPython Console.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: You probably have an error. Put a `@pause` at the end of the .bat to see what's going on.

Comment: you could also wrap the whole code before the last input inside a `try/except Exception as e: print(e)

Comment: @PRMoureu If the code throws an exception, the OP will see a printed stack trace.

Comment: I have added the @pause and it has not worked, the program still closes instantly.